# Where is the array getting that value from?

Tags: c++, arrays

So here's a simple program that just search for two numbers in an array that sum up to a certain value **k**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

unordered_set<int> hashtable;
int k =7;
int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int s = sizeof(arr);
for (int i =0; i<s; i++){
    if( hashtable.find(k - arr[i])!= hashtable.end() )
    {
       cout << arr[i] << endl;
       cout<< "found one " << arr[i] << " and "<< k-arr[i]<< endl;
    } else {
        hashtable.insert(arr[i]);
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

And here's the out put, I am getting

```
4
found one 4 and 3
5
found one 5 and 2
7
found one 7 and 0
7
found one 7 and 0
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Print the value of `s` and observe that it is not what you are assuming. Then read about what `sizeof` means in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: you miss to ask a question. Whats wrong with the output ? We only see the code and its output

Comment: the output prints `7` which doesn't exist in the arr variable

Comment: @YGouddi Please note that [`#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) is one of the worst things you could do.

Comment: No, i was playing around with unordered_set and i forgot to remove it afterwards

Answer (score 1):

You access the array outside of its bounds. The behaviour of the program is undefined.

`sizeof` does not yield the number of elements in an array. It yields the size of an object in bytes. When the size of the element is more than one byte - and `int` is more than one byte on most systems - then the number of bytes in the array is more than the number of elements.

A correct way to get the number of elements in an array is to use `std::size`:

```
int s = std::size(arr);
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that size is not a member of `std`

Comment: @YGouddi Did you include the header that defines `std::size`?

Comment: @YGouddi `std::size` is only available with C++17 and higher. Make sure you're using `C++17` so that you can use `std::size`. Also, don't forget to include the header for using `std::size`. For that you can write `#include <array>` etc.

Comment: which is what exactly?

Comment: @YGouddi Quite a few standard headers in fact. Check the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use only `arr[i]` and not `i` itself, you can write `for (auto a : arr)`. This will respect the array bounds, you don't need to calculate the maximum index. Hence, it avoids the wrong calculation (which the other answers fix)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are other ways to get the size of an array but for now this will do :

```
int s = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
```

Comment: Prefer `std::size`, it's actually type safe (as in, won't compile if you got the types wrong, as opposed to this).